# Why does NULL == 1 return logical(0) than FALSE?

Tags: r, null, logical-operators

Why does `NULL == 1` returns `logical(0)` instead of `FALSE`?

`identical(1, NULL)` returns `FALSE`, which is correct.

I know that `==` and `identical` cannot be used interchangeably, but what goes behind `NULL == 1` returning `logical(0)`?

Comment: Because `length(NULL)` returns zero. To test a `NULL` use `is.null`, as in `is.null(1)`.

Comment: More info in this [SO post](/questions/7195248/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-character0-in-r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an implicit type-coercion behind `"=="` (or any other logical operators) when two operands don't have the same mode. From `?"=="`:

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being "character", "complex", "numeric", "integer", "logical" and "raw".

This can give you some unbelievable result!

```
"0" == 0  ## TRUE
1L == 1.0 ## TRUE
```

Thus in `?identical`, it is mentioned that `"=="` is not really doing what people suppose it to do.

`identical` does no coercion. In fact, if you just look at the examples in `?identical`, you will see (I changed them a little bit):

```
identical(1, NULL) ## FALSE -- don't try this with ==
identical(1, 1L)   ## FALSE, stored as different types (modes)
```

`NULL` is amazingly versatile (or vague). See [elaborations here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52132824/4891738). What happens in `"=="` is that `NULL` is coerced to `numeric(0)` because `mode(1)` is `"numeric"`, and you are actually testing

```
numeric(0) == 1  ## NULL == 1
numeric(0) == c(1, 2)  ## NULL == c(1, 2)
```

Now the question is, why is the result `logical(0)`? Doesn't R's [recycling rule (R-intro)](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) applies? Why isn't the above code transformed to the following?

```
rep_len(numeric(0), 1) == 1  ## NA
rep_len(numeric(0), 2) == c(1, 2)  ## NA NA
```

Well, in [recycling rule (R-lang)](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Recycling-rules), it is said:

> As from R 1.4.0, any arithmetic operation involving a zero-length vector has a zero-length result.

Oh great; there is deliberately no recycling here. So we just get `logical(0)`.