# Why should someone use {} for initializing an empty object in R?

Tags: r, null

It seems that some [programmers](https://github.com/jdonaldson/rtsne/blob/master/tsne/R/tsne-internal.R) are using:

```
a = {}
a$foo = 1
a$bar = 2
```

What is the benefit over `a = list(foo = 1, bar = 2)`?

Why should `{}` be used? This expression only returns `NULL`, so a `NULL` assignment would do the same, wouldn't it?

Comment: it's likely a carry over from usage in other programming language. that particular GH user is a polyglot and sometimes old habits die hard.

Comment: I only found [6 instances on SO of `<- {}` using SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=&l=&e=%3C-+%7B%7D&n=&u=)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Your first query

> Why should `{}` be used, this expression only returns `NULL`, so an `NULL` assignment would do the same, wouldn't it?

Yes, `a <- NULL` gives the same effect. Using `{}` is likely to be a personal style.

---

#### `NULL`

`NULL` is probably the most versatile and confusing R object. From [R language definition of NULL](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#NULL-object):

> It is used whenever there is a need to indicate or specify that an object is absent. **It should not be confused with a vector or list of zero length.**
>
> The `NULL` object has no type and no modifiable properties. There is only one NULL object in R, to which all instances refer. To test for `NULL` use `is.null`. You cannot set attributes on `NULL`.

Strictly speaking, `NULL` is just `NULL`. And it is the only thing that `is.null` returns `TRUE`. However, according to `?NULL`:

> Objects with value NULL can be changed by replacement operators and will be coerced to the type of the right-hand side.

So, while it is not identical to a length-0 vector with a legitimate mode (*not all modes in R are allowed in a vector; read `?mode` for the full list of modes and `?vector` for what are legitimate for a vector*), this flexible coercion often makes it behave like a length-0 vector:

```
## examples of atomic mode
integer(0)  ## vector(mode = "integer", length = 0)
numeric(0)  ## vector(mode = "numeric", length = 0)
character(0)  ## vector(mode = "character", length = 0)
logical(0)  ## vector(mode = "logical", length = 0)

## "list" mode
list()  ## vector(mode = "list", length = 0)

## "expression" mode
expression()  ## vector(mode = "expression", length = 0)
```

You can do vector concatenation:

```
c(NULL, 0L)  ## c(integer(0), 0L)
c(NULL, expression(1+2))  ## c(expression(), expression(1+2))
c(NULL, list(foo = 1))  ## c(list(), list(foo = 1))
```

You can grow a vector (as you did in your question):

```
a <- NULL; a[1] <- 1; a[2] <- 2
## a <- numeric(0); a[1] <- 1; a[2] <- 2

a <- NULL; a[1] <- TRUE; a[2] <- FALSE
## a <- logical(0); a[1] <- TRUE; a[2] <- FALSE

a <- NULL; a$foo <- 1; a$bar <- 2
## a <- list(); a$foo <- 1; a$bar <- 2

a <- NULL; a[1] <- expression(1+1); a[2] <- expression(2+2)
## a <- expression(); a[1] <- expression(1+1); a[2] <- expression(2+2)
```

Using `{}` to generate `NULL` is similar to `expression()`. Though not identical, the run-time coercion when you later do something with it really makes them indistinguishable. For example, when growing a list, any of the following would work:

```
a <- NULL; a$foo <- 1; a$bar <- 2
a <- numeric(0); a$foo <- 1; a$bar <- 2  ## there is a warning
a <- character(0); a$foo <- 1; a$bar <- 2  ## there is a warning
a <- expression(); a$foo <- 1; a$bar <- 2
a <- list(); a$foo <- 1; a$bar <- 2
```

For a length-0 vector with an atomic mode, a warning is produced during run-time coercion (because the change from "atomic" to "recursive" is too significant):

```
#Warning message:
#In a$foo <- 1 : Coercing LHS to a list
```

We don't get a warning for expression setup, because from `?expression`:

> As an object of mode ‘"expression"’ is a list ...

Well, it is not a "list" in the usual sense; it is an *abstract syntax tree* that is list-alike.

---

#### Your second query

> What is the benefit over `a = list(foo = 1, bar = 2)`?

There is no advantage in doing so. You should have already read elsewhere that growing objects is a bad practice in R. A random search on Google gives: [growing objects and loop memory pre-allocation](https://www.r-craft.org/r-news/growing-objects-and-loop-memory-pre-allocation).

If you know the length of the vector as well as the value of its each element, create it directly, like `a = list(foo = 1, bar = 2)`.

If you know the length of the vector but its elements' values are to be computed (say by a loop), set up a vector and do fill-in, like `a <- vector("list", 2); a[[1]] <- 1; a[[2]] <- 2; names(a) <- c("foo", "bar")`.

---

#### In reply to [Tjebo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7941188/tjebo)

> I actually looked up `?mode`, but it doesn't list the possible modes. It points towards `?typeof` which then points to the possible values listed in the structure *TypeTable* in `src/main/util.c`. I have not been able to find this file not even the folder (OSX). Any idea where to find this?

It means the source of an R distribution, which is a ".tar.gz" file on CRAN. An alternative is look up on https://github.com/wch/r-source. Either way, this is the table:

```
TypeTable[] = {
    { "NULL",       NILSXP     },  /* real types */
    { "symbol",     SYMSXP     },
    { "pairlist",   LISTSXP    },
    { "closure",    CLOSXP     },
    { "environment",    ENVSXP     },
    { "promise",    PROMSXP    },
    { "language",   LANGSXP    },
    { "special",    SPECIALSXP },
    { "builtin",    BUILTINSXP },
    { "char",       CHARSXP    },
    { "logical",    LGLSXP     },
    { "integer",    INTSXP     },
    { "double",     REALSXP    }, /*-  "real", for R <= 0.61.x */
    { "complex",    CPLXSXP    },
    { "character",  STRSXP     },
    { "...",        DOTSXP     },
    { "any",        ANYSXP     },
    { "expression", EXPRSXP    },
    { "list",       VECSXP     },
    { "externalptr",    EXTPTRSXP  },
    { "bytecode",   BCODESXP   },
    { "weakref",    WEAKREFSXP },
    { "raw",        RAWSXP },
    { "S4",     S4SXP },
    /* aliases : */
    { "numeric",    REALSXP    },
    { "name",       SYMSXP     },

    { (char *)NULL, -1     }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Per R's documentation on braces and parentheses (type `?'{'` to read them), braces return the last expression evaluated within them.

In this case, `a <- {}` essentially "returns" a null object, and is therefore equivalent to `a <- NULL`, which establishes an empty variable that can then be treated as a list.

Incidentally, this is why it is possible to write R functions in which the function's output is returned simply by writing the name of the returned variable as the function's final statement. For example:

```
function(x) {
    y <- x * 2
    return(y)
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
function(x) {
    y <- x * 2
    y
}
```

Or even:

```
function(x) {
    y <- x * 2
}
```

The final line of the function being an assignment suppresses printing of the result in the console, but the function definitely returns the expected value if it saved into a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that `{}` returns the last evaluated expression, that was not meant the be the question. The question was about, why would one prefer to write `{}` instead of `NULL`. No one would write `a = {1}` instead of `a = 1` . Only because of saving three characters? I assume there are some drawbacks, like the parser is faster for a direct `NULL` assignment.